# Templated Member Function of Templated Class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have a templated C++ class which has a templated member function as well. The template parameters of this member function are dependent on the class's template parameters in a specific way (please see the code below).
I am instantiating (not specializing) this class for two different values of its template parameter. Everything compiles till this point. However, if I invoke the templated member function, the call for only the first instantiated object compiles and not the second one.
It appears as if the compiler is not instantiating the templated member function for the second instantiation of the template class. I am compiling the code below using "g++ filename.cpp" and am getting the following error:

filename.cpp:63: error: no matching function for call to 'Manager<(Base)1u>::init(Combination<(Base)1u, (Dependent2)0u>*)’

This is the line calling `b.init(&combination_2)`

g++ --version => g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-1ubuntu2) 4.4.7

uname -a => Linux 3.2.0-25-generic-pae #40-Ubuntu SMP i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

```
enum Base {
  AA,
  BB,
  CC
};

enum Dependent1 {
  PP,
  QQ,
  RR
};

enum Dependent2 {
  XX,
  YY,
  ZZ
};

template<Base B>
struct DependentProperty {
};

template<>
struct DependentProperty<AA> {
  typedef Dependent1 Dependent;
};

template<>
struct DependentProperty<BB> {
  typedef Dependent2 Dependent;
};

template <Base B, typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent D>
class Combination {
 public:
  void reset() {}
  int o;
};

template <Base B>
class Manager {
 public:
  template <typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent D,
            template<Base,
                    typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent> class T>
  void init(T<B, D>* t);
};

template <Base B>
template <typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent D,
          template<Base,
                  typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent> class T>
void Manager<B>::init(T<B, D>* t) {
  t->reset();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Manager<AA> a;
  Manager<BB> b;
  Combination<AA, PP> combination_1;
  Combination<BB, XX> combination_2;
  a.init(&combination_1);
  b.init(&combination_2);
  return 0;
}
```

It is not feasible to modify the classes corresponding to Base, Dependent or Combination from my example code in our actual project. What I am really wondering is whether my syntax for defining Manager::init() is wrong, or whether there is some known property/feature/constraint of C++ or g++ that wouldn't allow this code?

Comment: it would have been **wise** to use `typedef` before the definition of the template function init(). `typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent` is reapeated twice, and it really doesn't help understanding.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but this might be a compiler's bug

Answer (score 2):

The code below compiles for me, I have simplified your code a little, though it still does the same thing.

```
template <Base B>
class Manager {
 public:
typedef typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent D;  // if ever you need it
    template <typename TCombinaison>
    void init(TCombinaison* t)
    {
        t->reset();
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    typedef Combination<AA, PP> CombinaisonA;
    typedef Combination<BB, XX> CombinaisonB;

    typedef DependentProperty<AA> DependencyPropertyA;
    typedef DependentProperty<BB> DependencyPropertyB;

  CombinaisonA combination_1;
  CombinaisonB combination_2;

  Manager<AA> a;
  Manager<BB> b;

  a.init(&combination_1);
  b.init<&combination_2);

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: A 2nd solution so as to forbid the mixed use of combination in managers, as the OP has noticed in the comments below. Now I'm using std::is_same to check the "concept" contract.

```
template <Base B, typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent D>
class Combination {
 public:
    typedef typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent DependencyType;
  void reset() {}
  int o;
};

template <Base B>
class Manager {
 public:
    typedef typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent DependencyType; 
    template <typename TCombinaison>
    void init(TCombinaison* t)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<TCombinaison::DependencyType, Manager::DependencyType>);
        t->reset();
    }

};
```

Comment: It is different from my intended code because it allows b.init(&combination_1) to also compile. I want init() to only accept those Combination objects which share the same Base template parameter with the Manager object whose init() is being called.

Comment: @user2010172 I have modified the code accordingly, using `std::is_same` to check if the DependencyProperties are compatible.

Comment: Using std::is_same enforces compatibility but then there is one more difference from my intended code. In my intended code, init() could use the Dependent template parameter further (maybe to call other functions templated on that parameter), which it cannot now.  Another minor point: now we require every TCombinaison candidate to additionally define a public DependencyType for the purpose of this std::is_same check.

Comment: @user2010172 you are a little too fast in conclusion saying you can no longer... indeed the knowledge of type B and type D is accessible inside init(). Obviously your compiler, and also mine (VS2010 here) cannot deduce the types of the template template parameter. Maybe you should try some more explicit declarations.

Comment: You are right that it is _possible_ to get that information within init(), but can I get it without modifying all existing, and otherwise valid classes that satisfy requirements imposed by the template parameter T of init()?

Comment: without modifying TCollection candidates already existing... no... you're right.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine inheritance and go away from constant template parameters, extend the Combination to provide info on its template arguments, you can get the code to compile taking into account that you don't want this to compile:

```
b.init(&combination_1);
```

You are trying very hard to specify and fix the type of the Combination for the init member template within your Manager **indirectly**, even though the init template will deduce it since it is the only parameter of the function, and the type si defined within main anyway.

Would you consider templating the init directly with the Combination?

This way, everything apart from the init() declaration remains the same, and your code compiles as you wanted to initially:

```
class Base
{
};

class AA
:
    public Base
{
};

class BB
: 
    public Base
{
};

class Dependent1
{
};

class PP
:
    public Dependent1
{};

class Dependent2
{};

class XX
:
    public Dependent2
{};

template<class Base>
struct DependentProperty {
};

template<>
struct DependentProperty<AA> {
  typedef Dependent1 Dependent;
};

template<>
struct DependentProperty<BB> {
  typedef Dependent2 Dependent;
};

template <class Base> 
class Combination {
 public:

     typedef Base CombinationBase;
     typedef typename DependentProperty<Base>::Dependent CombinationDependent;

     void reset() 
     {

     }

     int o;
};


template <class Base>
class Manager
{
    public:

        // Any type C
        template<class C>
        void init (C* t)
        {
            // Any type C conforming to the implicit interface holding reset()
            t->reset(); 
            // Forcing specific combination
            Base b = typename C::CombinationBase(); 
            // Forcing it again
            typename DependentProperty<Base>::Dependent d = typename C::CombinationDependent();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  Combination<AA> combination_1;
  Manager<AA> a;
  a.init(&combination_1);

  Manager<BB> b;
  Combination<BB> combination_2;
  b.init(&combination_2);

  b.init(&combination_1);

  return 0;
}
```

In this case, you can extend the Combination template to provide access to its template parameters to the client code. Of course the template C in this case becomes a refinement of the Combination concept as soon as you rely on its implementation within the init member function (accessing the stored template argument values, etc).

Comment: This suggestion is indeed correct, but I've edited my original question above to reflect why I won't be able to take this route.

Comment: @user2010172 ok.. I'll take another look.. but it is weird that the first combination works, and not the second...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, except for the function calling part.

```
a.init<PP, Combination>( &combination_1 );
b.init<XX, Combination> ( &combination_2 );
```

This compiles and runs peacefully.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I see is

```
template <typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent D,
          template<Base, <-- wrong
                typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent <-- wrong
          > class T>
void init(T<B, D>* t);
```

Your class `Combination` waits **values** as a template parameter, but you want to give him **types**

I spent some time to fix it - like that

```
template <typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent D,
          template<Base BB,
                typename DependentProperty<BB>::Dependent DD
          > class T>
void init(T<B, D>* t);
```

and many other variants, but had no success.

Excuse me for arrange it as an answer, but I couldn't type so many code in a comment

Comment: `template<Base>` is the same as `template<Base BB>`.  Perhaps you were thinking of `template<typename Base>` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right. But what about `typename DependentProperty<B>::Dependent` ? What will template think about that `typename` ?